# Embed Protected PDF

Tags: files

Wondering if anyone has done this in Drupal 7.

I have a set of PDFs which need to be protected (i.e. restrict access). However, they also need to be displayed on a webpage (via the EMBED tags) for those users who have been authenticated.

What I have seen done in other systems is:

The PDFs are stored in a protected directory (e.g. PRIVATE)
There is also a PUBLIC directory
When the PDF is requested by an authenticated user, the PDF is copied from the PRIVATE directory to the public under an MD5 (with SALT) hashed name, and the filename is returned to the viewer.
Does this make sense, and has anyone done this in Drupal?

Answer (score 1):

Set the download method to private and implement [hook_file_download()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_file_download/7).

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but won't that affect an immediate download?  I want the PDF to be displayed via the <EMBED> tags.

Comment: `hook_file_download()` is invoked regardless of how the HTTP request was initiated (whether via <embed> tag, following a link, or entering the URL of the file in the address bar of the browser). Change the headers if the ones that Drupal generates do not suit your needs. Add URL arguments to the URL in the <embed> tag, if you want to send different headers only in the <embed> scenario. These URL arguments can then be evaluated by your `hook_file_download()`.